# Does using Identifying Many-To-One Relationship means having to have duplicate PRIMARY and FOREIGN keys on same table?

Tags: mysql, duplicates, foreign-keys, composite-primary-key

Original Title:  When PRIMARY KEY and foreign key INDEX are set on the same column names, does that mean that same index is duplicated?

Example:

I've generated a table using MySQL Workbench, and using Identifying relationship to other tables.  That means that PRIMARY KEY contains FOREIGN KEY columns in my case.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `price_history` (
`amount` DECIMAL NULL,
  `date_start` DATE NULL,
  `date_end` DATE NULL,
  `product_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `category_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `priceitem_id` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`product_id`, `category_id`, `priceitem_id`),
  INDEX `fk_idx` (`product_id` ASC, `category_id` ASC, `priceitem_id` ASC),
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

I note that `PRIMARY KEY` and `INDEX` define the same columns.  Does that mean I will have two separate "physical" indices on the table?  Won't that be wasteful?

I am wondering if it a necessary evil of identifying relationships.

Comment: the indexes are basically redundant. other than the specific `asc` ordering, they're dupes, so you're basically doubling the work the DB has to do anytime you add/change/delete records.

Comment: I could (and I did) have an `id` field on the table, which was inside the primary key index.  I removed it to accentuate the duplication.  In other words though .. identifying relationships in general create this sort of duplication, doubling the work.  I find that puzzling.

Comment: you can have as many indexes on a field as you want, either single-field indexes, or composite ones. the only harm it'll cause is the extra overhead of having to maintain them all. **IF** you **NEVER** have to do a query where you might use only SOME of the fields in the index, e.g. `where category_id=... and priceitem_id=...`, then feel free to do a composite key. but if you do need to access those fields in any partial combination, then you're probably better off with individual indexes on the fields. better to have separate indexes on the fields, rather than  multiple overlapping ones.

Comment: of course, if you need to do a `unique` index on those fields, then you do need to have that one composite key to enforce uniqueness on the tuple. individual unique indexes won't work, because `(1,2)` and `(1,3)` would be unique tuples, but making the components individually unique would trigger a duplicate key violation on the `1` value.

Comment: in my specific case I do need a `unique` constraint on the 3-tuple.  I don't need to have it in the primary key.  I was surprised however to see that if i was to do an identifying relationship, those columns would all go into the `primary key` as well, and that's where I started asking myself "do I really want an identifying relationship" practically even if it makes sense conceptually ...  it does not seem that identifying relationship will add anything here other than a duplicate index practically

Comment: InnoDB really needs a PK; your PK is fine.  A PK is, by definition, UNIQUE on the tuple.  I see no good reason for the FK to need the INDEX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see this happening if I understand your question. In the below, `price_history` does not have a db engine auto-created index that duplicates.

```
create table A
(   `product_id` INT NOT NULL,
    `category_id` INT NOT NULL,
    `priceitem_id` INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`product_id`, `category_id`, `priceitem_id`)

)ENGINE=INNODB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `price_history` (
    `amount` DECIMAL NULL,
    `date_start` DATE NULL,
    `date_end` DATE NULL,
    `product_id` INT NOT NULL,
    `category_id` INT NOT NULL,
    `priceitem_id` INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`product_id`, `category_id`, `priceitem_id`),
    FOREIGN KEY `f` (`product_id`, `category_id`, `priceitem_id`) references A(`product_id`, `category_id`, `priceitem_id`)
)ENGINE = InnoDB;

show create table price_history;
CREATE TABLE `price_history` (
   `amount` decimal(10,0) DEFAULT NULL,
   `date_start` date DEFAULT NULL,
   `date_end` date DEFAULT NULL,
   `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `category_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `priceitem_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`product_id`,`category_id`,`priceitem_id`),
   CONSTRAINT `price_history_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`product_id`, `category_id`, `priceitem_id`) 
      REFERENCES `a` (`product_id`, `category_id`, `priceitem_id`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB;

 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `price_history` (
    `amount` DECIMAL NULL,
    `date_start` DATE NULL,
    `date_end` DATE NULL,
    `product_id` INT NOT NULL,
    `category_id` INT NOT NULL,
    `priceitem_id` INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`product_id`, `category_id`, `priceitem_id`),
    FOREIGN KEY `f` (`product_id`, `category_id`, `priceitem_id`) references A(`product_id`, `category_id`, `priceitem_id`)
)ENGINE = InnoDB;

show create table A;
CREATE TABLE `a` (
   `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `category_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `priceitem_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`product_id`,`category_id`,`priceitem_id`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB;

 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `price_historyBBB` (
    id int auto_increment primary key,
    `amount` DECIMAL NULL,
    `date_start` DATE NULL,
    `date_end` DATE NULL,
    `product_id` INT NOT NULL,
    `category_id` INT NOT NULL,
    `priceitem_id` INT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY `g` (`product_id`, `category_id`, `priceitem_id`) references A(`product_id`, `category_id`, `priceitem_id`)
)ENGINE = InnoDB;

show create table price_historyBBB;
CREATE TABLE `price_historybbb` (
   `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `amount` decimal(10,0) DEFAULT NULL,
   `date_start` date DEFAULT NULL,
   `date_end` date DEFAULT NULL,
   `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `category_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `priceitem_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
   KEY `g` (`product_id`,`category_id`,`priceitem_id`),
   CONSTRAINT `price_historybbb_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`product_id`, `category_id`, `priceitem_id`) 
      REFERENCES `a` (`product_id`, `category_id`, `priceitem_id`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB;

show indexes from price_history;
show indexes from price_historyBBB;
```

So, if there exists an adequate key (say, composite) left-most chunk adequate enough for re-use, then the db engine will not auto-create a *Helper* index.

For instance, if you had a key (PK or otherwise) that was a composite of (col1,col2,col3,col5) and your FK called for the use of (col1,col2), then a new index is not auto-gen'd.

If the need for the FK was for (colX,col1,col2) then the above (col1,col2,col3,col5) is not useful (left-most priority) and the db engine will need to create an FK helper index.